# Analysis Services backup error: File system error: Access is denied

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup, ssas

This isn't your typical file system access is denied error. I am pretty perplexed by this issue.

I recently started getting errors from my nightly cube backup job.

> ```
> File system error:
> The following error occurred during a file operation: Access is denied.
> ```

I'm not aware of any recent changes to the permissions and they all seem to be intact.

I tried logging into the servers where the backups are located since. I find that even copying a file into the folder in question gives me an "Access is denied" dialog box.

**The kicker is that I only get "Access is denied" when I try to copy the `.abf` file into the folder.**

This also happens with the parent folder. I can copy `.bak` extensions and other files into the folder just fine. The account that is performing the backup has full permissions to the folder as well.

Why am I getting "Access is denied" errors, but only for `.abf` extensions?

I disabled the antivirus. Still getting access denied.

Comment: Is it in use by SSAS? Perhaps still being written to?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik Sorry my SSAS experience is limited. How can I check to see if it is in use?

Comment: I'd start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/use-dynamic-management-views-dmvs-to-monitor-analysis-services

Comment: Could you try to rename a .txt file to .abf and copy that over? Also, what is the size of your .abf file, maybe you are exceeding a disk quota?

Comment: @GeoffDawdy - did you get this sorted out?  What was the resolution?

Comment: @MaxVernon unfortunately I have had other items thrown onto my plate and implemented a workaround for this issue. I'm still unsure what or if there is a fix for this.

Comment: For anyone else who finds this question by googling 'Backup-ASDatabase File system error: The following error occurred during a file operation: Access is denied.' Check that the analysis services account has permissions on the folder (not just the account running the backup). That was what solved my issue (but I don't think it would answer the original question).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed similar error message on Windows Server 2016 / SQL Server 2017 by granting an access on backup folder to SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER) service account (NT Service\YourAccountName).

[image: Windows Server Services]